# How do I invoke a method from a custom module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, module

I've created a module in the `/lib` folder:

```
Module CookieHelper

   $str = cookies["shoppingcart"]

   def get_all_cookie_info()
   end

end
```

But this isn't working. If I move the code into a controller it works fine.

Also, I'm trying to invoke the method within this module. I've tried:

```
  require CookieHelper
  CookieHelper::get_all_cookie_info()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CookieHelper::get_all_cookie_info` is the correct way to call this method.

```
include CookieHelper
get_all_cookie_info
```

is another valid way, if you want include all of the methods in cookie helper available without having to namespace them (once the file lib/cookie_helper has been loaded).

What the issue probably is, is that the lib file isn't even required yet, this is because rails3 doesn't automatically load files in lib anymore. You can tell it to do so by editing your `application.rb` file, and setting inside `class Application < Rails::Application`

```
config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/lib )
```

Comment: as jwarchol, also pointed out, the bit in your code `$str = cookies["shoppingcart"]` look a bit odd, and more like php than ruby. If you want some help with the rest of what you're trying to achieve feel free to post a question for that too.

Answer (score 2):

to use methods from a module inside of an other class (such as a controller), you do something like this:

```
include CookieHelper
```

Once you do that inside of your controller's class, you can call get_all_cookie_info() with just the method name.

It sounds like you might be trying to something odd, so if you want to spell out what get_all_cookie_info is supposed to do, then maybe I can offer more advice.

Comment: This won't help the issue, that's equivalent to namespacing the method as he's already doing.